# why onreadystatechange function don't work in Windows

Tags: javascript, html

I was working on ubuntu, the script work very vell.
in Both OS he call the script but in windows he don't entre to the onreadystatechange function

Here is my script and the HTML.

```js
function readTextFile(file,str)
{
 var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
 rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
 {
  
  if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
  {
   if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
   {
    var allText = rawFile.responseText;
    if(allText.search(str) != -1){
     alert("exist");
     alert(location.pathname);
    }else{
     alert("not exist");
    }
   }
  }
 }
 rawFile.send(null); 
}
```

```html
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

<title>Title</title>
<script language="Javascript" src="C:/Users/to125286/Desktop/python_scraping/js/search.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div>
  <form name="search" onsubmit="return readTextFile('file:///C:/Users/to125286/Desktop/python_scraping/web/All-html.txt',this.string.value);">
   <input name="string" onchange="n = 0;">
   <input type="submit" value="Go">
  </form>
 </div>

<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Member Name</th>
<th>Birth-Death</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="">ADAMS, George Madison</a></td>
<td>1837-1920</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="">ALBERT, William Julian</a></td>
<td>1816-1879</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="">ALBRIGHT, Charles</a></td>
<td>1830-1880</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<h1>Member</h1>

</body>
```

i want to know if that have any relation with OS
you have ant idea why?

Thank you!

Comment: The console will most likely tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read a file on disk (`file:///` URL) using XMLHttpRequest. Many web browsers prevent this, as it can be a security risk. It is possible that whatever browser you are using on Windows is preventing it.

If you are using Chrome, you can:

1. **IMPORTANT**: Close all other Chrome windows. Make sure that no instance of `chrome.exe` is running, or this trick won't work.
2. Launch `chrome.exe` with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` command line option to temporarily disable the restriction.
3. Open the HTML file.